# How to change the android.jar precedence while using ant and external libs?

Tags: android, ant

I am trying to compile and build an android application using ant. I did `android update project --target 1 --path <path to project>` to create my build.xml. I am using api 16. I have some external jars that overwrite some of the classes and methods from android.jar and hence they need to be in the classpath before android.jar. Eclipse lets me reorder my precedence and hence I am able to work there. But while using ant, the way I give my external jar location is by having `jar.libs.dir=libs` and `external.libs.dir=libs` in build.properties file. But looks like they are added after the android.jar file in the compile task.

Is there a way I can change that?

Comment: Have you verified that this actually works on the device when built from eclipse?

Comment: Yes I have. Its already working. I am in the process of automating the build process.

Comment: But looks like ant uses android.jar in the bootstrap classpath for javac

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by overriding the compile target in the build.xml to have my custom jars as the bootstrap library and android.jar as classpath library.